# Can I get my Mac to wake from sleep for an SSH connection?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, ssh, wake-on-lan

I use Infuse on my iPad to play videos stored on my Mac.

However, after a few tens of minutes, the connection drops, and it doesn't reconnect. Restarting Infuse doesn't help. When I walk over to the computer, the hard disc light (it's an external disk) is off. When I move the mouse, the hard disc light comes on, and Infuse starts working again.

I tried unticking "Put hard discs to sleep when possible" and it made no difference. I tried resetting NVRAM and SMC and that didn't work either.

I now ticked "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off". Inufse now works reliably, but I don't like that the Mac is wasting energy, and possibly shortening the life of its components.

Configuration:

- iMac 5K (Late 2015), running 10.12.4, connected via Wifi
- Infuse Pro 5.4 on iPad 13-inch running iOS 10.3.1
- The connection is via SSH.

**How do I let my Mac go to sleep but wake up when Infuse connects via SSH?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake-on-Lan Protocol](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191387/wake-on-lan-protocol)

Comment: @VaddadiKartick so you want to wake from lan or wifi?  Because you talk about wifi in your but has it tagged as wake from lan.

Comment: Are you sure that Infuse connects over SSH in the first place? Also, does it really matter? Or is the question just "how can I prevent my Mac from sleeping while using Infuse to playback videos from its disk"? What have you already tried (including reaching out to the vendor)?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71524/can-i-prevent-a-remote-mac-from-entering-sleep-via-a-remote-ssh-connection?rq=1

Comment: @William Wifi. I used "wake-on-lan" more generally, not in the sense of a wired LAN.

Comment: @patrix Infuse connects over SSH, since it's the only protocol enabled on the Mac in System Preferences > Sharing. I don't know if the protocol matters. An alternative title to the question would be what you suggested, but I didn't use that since it's not an Infuse-specific question. I'm sure it would affect any other app or device I use to connect to the Mac, since the problem is with the Mac. As for the link to the "related" question you posted, I already set my Mac to never sleep, as my question says, so the related link isn't useful, at least to me.

Comment: @Allan Not a duplicate at all. I said so yesterday, but a mod seems to have mistakenly deleted my comment. The reason it's not a dupe is that that question, and its answers, talk of Linux, which I'm not using. I'm also not interested per se in knowing the protocol or other technical details. I'm interested in getting it working.

Comment: @patrix I contacted Infuse. Thanks for the suggestion.